# Android Studio change transparency of Image Assets

Tags: android, android-image, android-icons

When I create new "Image Asset" (Action Bar and Tab Icon) in Android Studio using my own icon as base, I get finally semi-transparent icons.  (Android Studio change original color transparency). How to prevent it and save original colors?


This is image before download to Android studio (pure black)

[image]

This is after download to Android studio with image asset and I set white color. It has became transparent.


[image]

Comment: A solution to consider: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62150079/7210237 
Similar to the response from @Gjchoza, but uses another official online tool.

Answer (score 15):

I also did this silly mistake...while adding an Image Asset.... Please notice the Shape option in the drop down. Select None so that the image will appear transparent in Android Studio.

[image: Find Android Studio Screen]

Comment: I didn't realize the area beneath `Icon Type` input is scrollable, and that there are other options there (including color!).  Thanks - nice pointer

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem, and found solution in post-convertation via imagemagick.

```
convert ic_action.png -fuzz 50% -channel RGBA -fill white -opaque white ic_action.png
```

We select all semi-white color and replace to pure white. Also for black:

```
convert ic_action.png -fuzz 50% -channel RGBA -fill black -opaque black ic_action.png
```

It is result:

[image: Before and after]

And finally some tips and tricks, how to convert ic_action.png in one line in bash. Do it from project root.

Firstly find all files of icon:

```
find app/src -name "ic_action_name.png"
```

Next get it with `xargs` with name `ICON`:

```
xargs -iICON
```

And get command:

```
find app/src -name "ic_action_name.png" | xargs -iICON convert ICON -fuzz 50% -channel RGBA -fill white -opaque white ICON
```

Replace `ic_action_name.png` to your icon name, and if need `white` to `black` or other color (imagemagick also supports RGB syntax `'#FF0000'`).

Comment: For mac os xargs's, use `xargs -IICON` (big "I" instead of small "i") :

Answer (score 2):

You can unchecked this icon to see the background color...

[image: one]

Comment: thank's for attention. Yeh right, but it's really  change transparent of icon. I update my question and add new image and description. you can see also my question this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882124/android-tab-icon-color-is-not-clear?noredirect=1#comment61335815_36882124

Comment: @ElamanAitymbet well... do you need the icon with background or not? I'm really don't understand what do you need it.

Comment: I only want to change image color from black to white with Image Asset.Only! But when I use it in tablayout icon I found that  icon color transparent

Comment: @ElamanAitymbet Why don't change the icon background with another program like `photoshop` or similar and import on project with background color? or... you can put the icon inside a `LinearLayour` (or another) and put a `background Color` to the `layout` in background

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to remove default background color in android studio 3.0

step 1: select new image assert in mipmap folder 
           mipmap->new->image Assert

step 2: select **foreground tab** and load your icon image in file location path,
adjust  the image  set according to your view  the available option like (trim, resize)

step 3:  then select background tab and delete the path from the path locator tab.
step 4: go to `ic_lancher.xml` file under the mipmap folder,
then delete

the line of code.

step 5: do the same operation on `ic-launcher_round.xml` file under mipmap folder

```
 <background  android :drawable="@mipmap/ic_lancher_round_background"/>
```

then you can find your icon without android studio default green cover background.
[step_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpZ8F.png) [step_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b19fZ.png)[step_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7cIS.png)
[step_4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDVbX.png)

Answer (score 2):

For correct this unwanted **alfa**, I make sure that ***Android Studio*** create a **XML** for this drawable, than I edit it, like here "ic_cinema.xml":

[image: ic_cinema.xml]

So, now I remove or edit alfa parameter

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:alpha="0.8"> <!-- HERE YOU MAKE YOUR CHANGE -->
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M18,4l2,4h-3l-2,-4h-2l2,4h-3l-2,-4H8l2,4H7L5,4H4c-1.1,0 -1.99,0.9 -1.99,2L2,18c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h16c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V4h-4z"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did not find a way to configure the Image Asset (Action Bar and Tab Icon) so it would not generate semi-transparent icons.

However, if you select "Notification Icons" instead of "Action Bar and Tab Icons", the generated icon set is not semi-transparent (it is opaque). I'm currently using the generated icons for my Action Bars and Tabs.

Alternatively, I found the following website https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html which mimics the Image Asset Studio and generates opaque icon sets.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Gjchoza for this.
The only thing that helped me create nice icons exactly how I needed them was [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) site.

Not even Android Studio 4.0's Image Asset Creation tool could provide for my needs.