# Android toolbar icon color not so bright

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-styles

I am developing an app in which there are multiple tabs with icon without any title. The problem is that the icons are not looking as bright it should. I used white color(FFFFFF) in creating icon assets. Still it doesn't looks so good.

[image]

The pic above shows Facebook Messenger and my App. There is difference between color(although both are white).
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You can create the images yourself and put them inside the appropriate folders, alternatively you can import the images an Launcher icons.

Comment: As mentioned, i ve created those images using image asset option in android studio. Also the title is also not so bright. You can see and compare with both e images

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I have experienced similar problem. I think it is fault of android asset studio when I create icon with white in reality they are no white as I expected.Then I found very good online studio which is same as Android asset studio even better than that. Solution for this I think you have create icon out from AS then import them to appropriate folders.Here online icon generate web site [link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=add_circle&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_add_circle&theme=light&color=rgba(33%2C%20150%2C%20243%2C%200.6))

Answer (score 0):

*Note: The question is old, but I consider sharing this information could be useful for anyone who could stumble upon this issue in the future.*

If you use the Asset Studio tool from the Android Studio your icons will contain 
alpha channel with a value of 60% (value depends on selected colour). I provided an example below.

In case you can use vector graphics it should work for you because you can freely edit XML file describing the generated image. Just remove `android:alpha=".."` attribute.

If you cannot use vector graphics and want to avoid transparency use this official [online tool from Google](https://material.io/resources/icons/) to generate material icons for your application.

This tool supports multiple sizes, black and white colours, and SVG as well as PNG format:

[image: Example generating icon using online tool from Google at https://material.io/resources/icons/]

Issues example of 60% alpha channel in Android Studio:

[image: Selecting any icon to generate an example]

[image: Example generated, alpha channel is set to 0.6]