# How to create Material action bar icons in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, material-design

When I right click on the drawable folder => New => Image Asset => Action Bar and Tab Icons => Theme
I can only select HOLO_LIGHT, HOLO_DARK and CUSTOM. Even when I use custom with #FFFFFF the icons are a bit transparent.

The Android Asset Studio website https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html creates icons without transparency, but they are too small

Is there a quick way to create material icons?

Comment: Use Asset Studio that is built in Android Studio. Press shift twice and type in `Asset Studio`. You will get `Image Asset` and `Vector Asset` tools to create icons. Fast, easy and reliable. But be aware, that images are created with transparency. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62150079/7210237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change icon color by setting the item `tint`, check below example

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_next"
    android:tint="#FFDE2F"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

create a file in drawable folder if icon is raster image- `drawable_icon_next.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
   android:tint="#FFDE2F"/>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#FFDE2F" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#FFDE2F" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

And use this drawable for item.

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_next"
   android:icon="@drawable/drawable_icon_next"
   android:title="Menu title"
   app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: Will this change transparency?

Comment: Icon color will changed to the color that you are specified as tint color

Comment: I have a android:icon inside a <item> element and tint doesnt seem to work here